# xamarin method no found GoToAsync

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to open a viewpage, from a searchhandler using await Shell.Current.GoToAsync ("User"); already register the route in appshell Routing.RegisterRoute ("User", typeof (User)); but I still get the result
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task Xamarin.Forms.Shell.GoToAsync(Xamarin.Forms.ShellNavigationState)'

xamarin.forms version 4.5.0.617

thank you

Comment: xamarin.forms version 4.5.0.617

Comment: How does your XAML look like? Looking at the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation it seems to only apply to fly out items, tab and shell content

Comment: it´s not from FlyoutItem, it´s from a button. Thank you.

Comment: I came to the result that the problem was due to the xamarin.forms version, I down it from version 4.5.0.617 to version 4.4.0.991265 and this worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the result that the problem was due to the xamarin.forms version, I down it from version 4.5.0.617 to version 4.4.0.991265 and this worked.
Thank